# error Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab

I am using thresh_tool function to manually threshold an image with this properties `183x275x3 uint8` and this error showed up **"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts**

Error in ind2rgb (line 34)

```
rout(:,:,1) = r;"
```

i tried to set the cmap to '**gray**' and the error still show up,so I deg into the code I figured that the error is in the inner function "`function rgb = im2rgb(im,full_map); %nested"`
in this line"    `rgb = ind2rgb(ind,full_map);'`

this is the code

```
img= imread('brain9.jpg');
[level,bw]=thresh_tool(img,'gray',0.7)
```

this is the code inside thresh_tool where the error happen

```
function rgb = im2rgb(im,full_map); %nested
    %coerce intensities into gray range [0,1]
    gray = imadjust(im,[],[0 1]);
    %generate indexed image
    num_colors = size(full_map,1);
    ind = gray2ind(gray,num_colors);
    %convert indexed image to RGB
    rgb = ind2rgb(ind,full_map);
  end %im2rgb
```

i expected to have manual level and a binary image as an output 
and whos function gived me this before the error
 Name              Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

full_map          1x3                    24  double
  gray            183x275x3            150975  uint8
  img             183x275x3            150975  uint8
  ind             183x275x3            150975  uint8
  num_colors        1x1                     8  double
[medical image that i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdqKt.jpg)

Comment: Apparently, this function is expecting a grayscale image and you are passing it an RGB image. If you're having problems, perhaps it would be better to contact the author, since this is not a standard MATLAB  function.

Comment: Thanks I think the problem is with the image type ,because I changed the image and it worked just fine.